# Firebase ObserveEvent childAdded wait until done

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using the new firebase api to observe a child path in the realtime database called "posts"

Here is one JSON Entry:

```
"posts" : {

"-KLT6oYF-F_5sf-dC_2R" : {
  "items" : {
    "item1" : {
      "location" : "Post Street Mall",
      "name" : "Glasses",
      "price" : "199",
      "vendor" : "Clicks"
    }},      
  "tags" : "summer, casual, urban ",
  "title" : "Casual Summer "
}
```

The problem is whenever I add something to "posts" the childAdded event is fired and my app database updates. Unfortunately not all the data has been added yet using setValue().

Is there a way to only write to the database when all the items and has been added? And then when all the data for one post has been added, send the childAdded signal to the app?

Any help is much appreciated.

Basic sample code follows:

```
    // CREATING DATABASE OBSERVER TO SCAN POSTS

    let postRef = database.child("posts")
    // CONNECTING OBSERVER AND CHECKING FOR NEW ITEMS
    postRef.observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) -> Void in

     // This is in a different class
     postDBRef.child("title").setValue(self.mainImageTxt?.text) // I think this triggers the child added already?                postDBRef.child("tags").setValue(self.tagsTxt?.text?.lowercaseString)                
     // getting cell data
     for rowIndex in 0..<self.stepperValue {
         let cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: rowIndex, inSection: 0)) as! AddPostTableViewCell
         let itemName = cell.itemNameTxt.text!
         postDBRef.child("items/item\(rowIndex + 1)/name").setValue(itemName)
          }
```

Comment: wich language are you using?

Comment: wasnt sure if this is so relevant because its more a firebase api thing. But I am using swift 2.0

Comment: actually it isnt. But its nice so we can write you some examples in the right language :)

Comment: okay, thanks for the input

Comment: Are you saying the childAdded event is called before a single setValue statement has written all of it's data? If so, that's unusual.

Comment: @Jay I have one setValue for the main post, and then a loop which adds all the sub items. So when the first setValue is set, it fires the signal. And also when iterating over the sub items the signal is fired each loop. I will share the code just now.

Comment: Oh oh. Don't do that! Build an object in code, say a dictionary and write it out at one time! That will eliminate having to do that iteration. You can then do setValue(myObject) and the problem goes away.

Comment: I ve just added the sample code.

Comment: Yep. Get rid of that setValue and build a dictionary (that would be the same structure as your Firebase) and one write will do it.

Comment: Didn't know I could do that! Thanks Jay. I will let you know how it goes :)

Comment: You just saved me from a 10h headache! Thanks bud! Please add an answer and I will vote it up!

Comment: Done and I threw some code in the answer too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build an object in code, say a dictionary and write it out at one time! That will eliminate having to do that iteration. You can then do setValue(myObject) and the problem goes away.

I whipped up some quick code to produce the data structure similar to what you're using. This will build the structure in code and then write it out with one setValue.

Assume you want the following data structure

```
items
  item4
    name: some item 3
  item8
    name: some item 7
```

Here's how to do get that in code

```
    let stepperValue = 10
    var myDict = [String:  [String: String] ]()

    for rowIndex in 0..<stepperValue {
        let itemName = "some item \(rowIndex)"
        let childDict = ["name": itemName]
        let parentKey = "item\(rowIndex + 1)"
        myDict[parentKey] = childDict
    }

    let ref = myRootRef.childByAppendingPath("items")
    ref.setValue(myDict)
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You could simply go with `updateChildValues`, keeping the changes you want to write in an array

```
 let childUpdates = ["/posts/\(postKey)": postData,
                    "/posts/\(anotherPostId)": anotherPostData]
```

And when you have all the posts you want to update you just call

```
ref.updateChildValues(childUpdates)
```

This will write the data once and it will call one ChildAdded event for each child you have added.

Documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/save-data#update_specific_fields).

Comment: I will give this a go! I hope its that easy! Thanks :)